# datetime.time() inserted in strftime

Tags: python, strftime

I am wondering if someone could explain why my strftime returns elements I have not asked for:

```
def CurrentTime():
    import datetime as dt
    myTime = dt.datetime.today().time()  
    print(myTime, type(myTime))
    strFromTime =  myTime.strftime("%I:%M %r")
    return strFromTime, type(strFromTime)
CurrentTime()
```

10:40:54.160337  ,   'datetime.time'>

('10:40 **10:40:54** AM', str)

Comment: %r does `10:40:54 AM`, what is wrong?. Maybe you were trying to do: `"%I:%M %p"`. See docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I believe you're looking for %p

Comment: Another note: In python libraries should be imported in the beginning of the script. In this case you should move import datetime as dt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna write how I would simplify this, [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more info.

```
import datetime as dt

def CurrentTime():
    # Returns time in format %I:%M %p, e.g. '06:59 PM'
    myTime = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")
    return myTime

print(CurrentTime())
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have looked at a different table or misread to get the %r specifier. It seems just using "%r" results in: '11:23:21 AM', which is interesting. I found a full list here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: @TASCSolutions Glad it worked out fo rya. I linked to the list aswell (the Python docs)